# How can I generate a listing of birthdays and anniversaries in FamilyTreeBuilder?

Tags: myheritage.com, family-tree-builder

I've been building a family tree with [FamilyTreeBuilder](https://www.myheritage.com/family-tree-builder). How can I generate a listing of birthdays and anniversaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Export the CSV of names, birthdays, and anniversaries:

   1. Click on Reports -> Export Custom Report
   2. If applicable, filter to "Selected People" to filter the selection to a specific person's spouses and descendants.
   3. Save the CSV file
2. Convert the CSV to a PDF

   1. Install ReportLab (`pip install reportlab`)
   2. Download `familytreebuilder_to_pdf.py` (from: https://github.com/moshekaplan/FamilyTreeBuilder_csv_to_PDF)
   3. Run the script as follows: `python familytreebuilder_to_pdf.py -i report.csv -o output.pdf`

**Sample output:**

[image]

The graphic above is built from the sample data included with FamilyTreeBuilder.

Comment: This seems like advertising to me, ask a question then post the answer recommending self written software.

Comment: I couldn't find an existing software solution, so I wrote my own. If there's a tool that would do it for me, I'd have strongly preferred that option.

Comment: Also,with regards to answering my own question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ where it says: "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."